# Split date into different columns for year, month and day

Tags: r, date

I have zoo objects that look like:

head(obs)

```
      Index pp
1932-01-01  0
1932-01-02  0.2
1932-01-03  0
```

and I want to split the index into 3 columns (years, months and days in separate columns) so I can do some analyses per day of month using `ddply`.

I don't know if it makes any difference but my dates were created using:

```
dates <- as.Date(CET[,1], "%d-%m-%Y")
obs <- xts(CET[,2], dates)
```

where CET is the original file with dates in column 1 and pp in column 2.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1) **columns**.  We can use lubridate's `year`/`month`/`day` or chron's `month.day.year`:

1a) **columns via lubridate**

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(1:1000, as.Date("1932-01-01") + 0:999)

library(lubridate)
tt <- time(z)
zz <- cbind(z, year = year(tt), month = month(tt), day = day(tt))
```

1b) **columns via chron**

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(1:1000, as.Date("1932-01-01") + 0:999)

library(chron)
zz <- with(month.day.year(time(z)), zoo(cbind(z, day, month, year)))
```

2) **aggregate**.  However, we do not really need to create columns in the first place.  We can just use `aggregate.zoo` directly with the original zoo object, `z`, using lubridate or chron or just using `yearmon` from zoo depending on what it is that you want to do:

2a) **aggregate using lubridate**

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(1:1000, as.Date("1932-01-01") + 0:999)

library(lubridate)
aggregate(z, day, mean)
aggregate(z, month, mean)
aggregate(z, year, mean)
```

2b) **aggregate using chron**

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(1:1000, as.Date("1932-01-01") + 0:999)

library(chron)
mdy <- month.day.year(time(z))

aggregate(z, mdy$day, mean)
aggregate(z, mdy$month, mean)
aggregate(z, mdy$year, mean)

# or
ct <- as.chron(time(z))

aggregate(z, days(ct), mean)
aggregate(z, months(ct), mean)
aggregate(z, years(ct), mean)

# days(ct) and years(ct) can actually
# be shortened to just days and years within the above context
# (and that would work for months too except they would be out of order)
aggregate(z, days, mean)
aggregate(z, years, mean)
```

2c) **aggregate using yearmon**

If we wish to summarize each year/month rather than lumping all January months together, all February months together, etc. then we need neither chron nor lubridate but rather can use zoo's `yearmon`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(1:1000, as.Date("1932-01-01") + 0:999)

aggregate(z, yearmon, mean)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
dtstr <- as.character( index(CET))

CET$yr <- sapply(strsplit(dtstr, "-") , "[", 1)
CET$mon <- sapply(strsplit(dtstr, "-") , "[", 2)
CET$dt <- sapply(strsplit(dtstr, "-") , "[", 3)
```

Comment: thanks DWin, `index(CET)` doesn't work (`Error: could not find function "Index"`) but changing to  `dtstr <- as.character( CET[,1])`, works!

Comment: Glad it got you where you need. Note: The function is spelled `index`, not `Index`

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
CET$year <- format(CET[,1], "%Y") # year
CET$month <- format(CET[,1], "%m") # month
CET$day <- format(CET[,1], "%d") # day
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work: `Error in format.default(structure(as.character(x), names = names(x), dim = dim(x),  : 
  invalid 'trim' argument`

Comment: It seems like your dates were factors. You can use the str() function to make sure that you dates are actually dates.

Answer (score 2):

```
require(lubridate)
maindata1 <- cbind(maindata1, day=day(maindata1$Date), month=month(maindata1$date), year=year(maindata1$date))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about the code, and not just a code dump.