# Split Date to Day, Month and Year for ffdf Data in R

Tags: r, date, ffbase, ff

I'm using R's `ff` package with `ffdf` objects named `MyData`, `(dim=c(10819740,16))`. I'm trying to split the variable Date into Day, Month and Year and add these 3 variables into `ffdf` existing data `MyData`.

For instance: My Date column named `SalesReportDate` with `VirtualVmode` and `PhysicalVmode = double` after I've changed `SalesReportDate` to `as.date(,format="%m/%d/%Y")`.

Example of `SalesReportDate` are as follow:

```
> B
  SalesReportDate
1       2013-02-01
2       2013-05-02
3       2013-05-04
4       2013-10-06
5       2013-15-10
6       2013-11-01
7       2013-11-03
8       2013-30-02
9       2013-12-12
10      2014-01-01
```

I've refer to [Split date into different columns for year, month and day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550678/split-date-into-different-columns-for-year-month-and-day) and try to apply it but keep getting error warning.

So, is there any way for me to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: require(ffbase);
MyData$SalesReportDateYear <- with(MyData["SalesReportDate"], format(SalesReportDate, "%Y"), by = 250000)

Comment: It's work, thank you so much @jwijffels , really appreciate that..but can I know, why we need to add by=250000, what does it means? I'm new in this..

Comment: You don't need to add the by argument, but if you specify it, it will loop in chunks of 250000 records in this example. If you don't specify it, it will look at the RAM you specified in getOption("ffbatchbytes") to see how much can be processed in 1 chunk without overblowing your RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @jwijffels for this great solution:

```
require(ffbase)

MyData$SalesReportDateYear <- with(MyData["SalesReportDate"], format(SalesReportDate, "%Y"), by = 250000) 

MyData$SalesReportDateMonth <- with(MyData["SalesReportDate"], format(SalesReportDate, "%m"), by = 250000) 

MyData$SalesReportDateDay <- with(MyData["SalesReportDate"], format(SalesReportDate, "%d"), by = 250000)
```