# How can I separate date into year,month and day column? Date column is recorded as "2012-Jan-03"

Tags: r

I have a big datafile with over 1000 entries,  I want to separate date into year,month and day column. I have tried using as.Date(x), it gave me an error. Strptime (x,format="%y-%m-%d"),returns MAs. Someone out the to help me.the date column is coded as "2012-Jan-03"

Comment: Convert to date first with `df$col <- as.Date(df$col, "%Y-%b-%d")` and then use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550678/split-date-into-different-columns-for-year-month-and-day

Answer (score 0):

Does this give what you want ?

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(date = "2012-Jan-03") %>%
  separate(date, into =c("year","month","day"), sep ="-")
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  year  month day  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2012  Jan   03
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date <- "2012-Jan-03"

df <- data.frame(
  year = format(as.Date(date, "%Y-%b-%d"), "%Y"),
  month = format(as.Date(date, "%Y-%b-%d"), "%b"),
  day = format(as.Date(date, "%Y-%b-%d"), "%d")
)

df
  year month day
1 2012   Jan  03
```